# Book a cab on my behalf, the code is not production ready, how to proceed then?

Tags: uber-api, uberjar

[image]I am trying to do an auto-booking of a cab from my code for uber, only for me.
I have my clientID, client Secret and Access Token. How to use them so that i can fire a request and monitor the status whether has been booked or not? Or if no cabs are available it would retry at specific intervals unless a cab gets booked.
Please guide me.
In the meantime while i am trying to fire a v1/me, i am getting 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: And yes, negative voters, please cite a reason before you vote this as negative, then i would get the point as where i am going wrong in asking something like this.

Comment: I added a param as access_token also to add my access token.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [try following the Authentication tutorial](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/authentication#oauth-20) to understand if the requests you fire are as expected?

Also, you're getting down voted because there is code or anything that would enable us to help you debug this issue. If the hints in the tutorial do not help, please provide more details on the headers you add. You need to have the authorization header: `Authorization: Bearer <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>` with a valid access_token.